# No files eagerly loaded in meteor application other than main.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, import

After having created a simple meteor application with the newest meteor 1.8 client:

```
meteor create testapp
```

and then adding a file under the path `server/test.js`, I would expect the file `main.js` and `test.js` beeing eagerly loaded server side. Nevertheless only `main.js` is loaded server side.

In the [meteor documentation about file structure](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#javascript-structure) `main.js` is reported to be the main entry point, but not to be the only file eagerly imported if present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is a section in the `package.js`, that is beeing created by `meteor create`

```
{
  ...,
  "meteor": {
    "mainModule": {
      "client": "client/main.js",
      "server": "server/main.js"
    },
    "testModule": "tests/main.js"
  }
}
```

in the [changelog to 1.8](https://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html#changes-8) they mention this behavior.

> When specified, these entry points override Meteor's default module loading semantics, rendering imports directories unnecessary. If mainModule is left unspecified for either client or server, the default rules will apply for that architecture, as before. To disable eager loading of modules on a given architecture, simply provide a mainModule value of false.

So the solution is to remove the `mainModule` section from the `package.json`.